# How to permanently disconnect an Acceptor session

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

Is it possible to disconnect an Acceptor session in QuickFIX/J ? I have tried the method `disconnect(String reason, boolean logError)`. But once the counterparty tried to reconnect then the session is reconnected.

What i want is to **stay disconnected**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the javadoc comment for the `disconnect()` method you should rather not call it from user code:

```
     * This method should not be called from user-code since it is likely
     * to deadlock when called from a different thread than the Session thread
     * and messages are sent/received concurrently.
     * Instead the logout() method should be used where possible.
```

So please use the `logout()` method to log out from a Session. It will also disable the Session in a way that counterparties will be logged out when connecting. But there can be a short timeframe when they will be logged on. This is because that flag is only checked once a second.

To reject a Logon right away, you could throw a `RejectLogon` Exception out of your `fromAdmin()` callback.

Update: Starting from QuickFIX/J 2.3.0 the Acceptor session will stay disconnected after calling `logout()`. See https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/pull/360

Comment: I am expecting a mechanism to manually logout and stay logged out (in other words stay disconnected) until manually allow to logon. But, when I try the logout() method, if the counter party tries to logon then system allowing it.
I tried to set a RejectReason while I'm manually logout() in order to throw RejectLogon as you mentioned, this message was not available when the Logon request received. So, I cannot maintain the session logged out.

Comment: To throw `RejectLogon` you need to really *throw* `RejectLogon` out of `fromAdmin()` as I mentioned. It won't work to throw it from `logout()`. So first call `logout()`, then put a check into your `fromAdmin()` to throw `RejectLogon` when a `Logon` comes in. That will reject incoming `Logons`.

Comment: Before i throw the `RejectLogon` from `fromAdmin`, i want to make sure this logout is imposed manually. So, i would like to validate the `LogoutReason` for the corresponding session's `state`. But, it is getting nullified before it reach to the method `fromAdmin()`. Any idea to handle this situation?

Comment: You mean you only want to throw `RejectLogon` if you formerly decided to logout manually? Can't you store a boolean flag somewhere in your application? And then simply check if that boolean flag has been set to `true`? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: We can go for the boolean flag suggestion @ChristophJohn. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Comment: @MuhammadhAadhil I've updated my answer. With QFJ 2.3.0 the session will stay disconnected after `logout()`.